# core.js:183 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor MatCommonModule cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've tried completely removing material and then installing it again but no use. I've also tried removing the node modules and installing them again with a simple `npm install`.
The full error on the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor MatCommonModule cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js (core.js:183)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/icon.js (icon.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/material/material.module.ts (material.module.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.module.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i ran into the same thing today. Fixed it by downgrading from material 10 to material 9

Comment: Can you maybe shed a bit more light on why this happens? It could happen with other libraries I've installed too?

Comment: Solved my problem

Comment: @HackleSaw I wish I knew :D